# Why does list value instead of str in unit test?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a class with two attributes strings, but in unit test return a list ('Test',) instead of string 'Test'.

Model:

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self, document:str, name:str):
        self.name = name,
        self.document = document
```

Unit test:

```
def test_create_company(self):
       company = Company(name='Test', document='1111111111')
       self.assertEqual('Test', company.name)
```

Error:

```
>       self.assertEqual('Test', company.name)
E       AssertionError: 'Test' != ('Test',)
```

Comment: There's no way this exact code behaves like this. You probably have a stray comma after `self.name = name` in your code.

Comment: thanks! This solved!

Comment: `self.document = document,` instantiates `self.document` as a tuple and not a string, remove that `,`